# Should Rails controllers be tested for validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I have a question about what parts of a controller should be tested in a Ruby on Rails application. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

When I create new models that need validations such as `validates :name, presence: true`, I always write tests for these models. For example (if the model name is User):

```
test "name should be present" do
    assert_not User.new({ name: nil }).valid?
end
```

However, I also have a controller that "goes with" the model (e.g Users). Should I also test that the controller validates its parameters even though I am already testing the model?

Example:

```
test "invalid user should not be created" do
    assert_no_difference "User.count" do
        post random_models_path, store: { name: " " }
    end
end
```

I definitely am still going to test that a *valid* store *is* created, but should I check that an *invalid* store is *not* created?

Thanks

### Edit

Would it be a good idea to just test the controller for only one of the possible invalid case, because if that one succeeds then I know that the model validations are probably working?

Comment: Personally, I don't see the point in testing effects of validations even in models. Most I do is verify that the validations _are_ there. `it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of :name }`. Why spend the effort to repeat the activerecord's tests?

Comment: Can I do the same thing (`it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of :name }`) in minitest instead of rspec?

Comment: You probably can, but I have no idea how. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be a good idea to just test the controller for only one of the possible invalid case, because if that one succeeds then I know that the model validations are probably working?

That's the right idea, and is generally what I do. There's no need to test every possible combination of validation states in the controller, but it's a good idea to test two general conditions:

1) For a valid model do we save it and redirect to where we should? (Or do we render the right thing in response?)

2) For an invalid model (for any of the possible reasons it could be invalid), do we re-render the form in such a way that the user can correct the error.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks so much!